# Is it possible to use "steps" inside SitePrism pages?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

I'm working in a cucumber-ruby framework and we're using Capybara and SitePrism to drive the browser.

I've got a situation where I want to retry a bunch of steps if an error happens, so I was putting a method with logic to cover this within a SitePrism page as follows:

```
steps %Q{
When I click on the back button
And I enter my reference number
Then I am able to complete the action successfully
}
```

The problem I'm finding is that when this part of code is reached, the execution fails with:

```
    undefined method `steps' for #<MySitePrismPage:0x000000063be5b0 @loaded=false> (NoMethodError)
```

Any idea if there's a way for me to use steps within SitePrism pages?

Thanks!

Comment: I thought it was a problem with SitePrism pages, but I've just tried with a standard class or even a module and I keep on getting the same issue about 'undefined method steps'. If anyone has a suggestion that I could try pls?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to 'Jonas Maturana Larsen' in a [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-android/rb7yt0e0nVk). Similar problem with a different example, but passing 'world' to the class fixed the problem for me as well.

> step is defined in Cucumbers RbWorld module.
>
> You need to pass in the world instance from where ever you're creating
>   the TestRubyCallStep class.
>
> In your case you might actually want to make a module instead of a
>   class if you just need a place to keep shared methods.
>
> ```
> class TestRubyCallStep   
>     include Calabash::Android::Operations   
>
>     def initialize(world)
>         @world = world   
>     end   
>
>     def callMethod
>         @world.step %Q{my customized steps in custom_step.rb}   
>     end 
> end
> ```
>
> The context in which the step definition is executed *is* the world :)
>
> Try this:
>
> ```
> Then /^I call a step from Ruby class "([^\"]*)"$/ do |world|   
>     testObj = TestRubyCallStep.new(self)   
>     testObj.callMethod 
> end
> ```

Answer (score 0):

*Old question but providing answer*

Using `steps` as a method call is considered an anti-pattern and is being deprecated / removed going forwards in cucumber.

It is *highly advisable* to instead extract out the common behaviour into Helper Modules / Classes, and then call the methods on those.

Furthermore as you've found out. Running inside the Cucumber World, extends all of the cucumber methods into a top level DSL, so simply calling `steps` will work. Whereas that DSL is never mixed into any SitePrism context, so you cannot do it.

TL;DR - Don't do what you're trying to do. Do something like this.

```
module MyReusableHelper
  def click_back
    # verbose code here
  end

  def enter_reference_number
    # verbose code here
  end

  def complete_action # Note this method name probably needs a rethink
    # verbose code here
  end
```

Then simply include this module into whichever class/es need it.

If you have any more queries, ask here or if you're convinced something is broke post on the Official GH page.